# How to perform integration over product of matrices?

Tags: matrix-calculus

My goal is to express the result of the following integral in closed-form (using for example traces of the matrices):

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} b^T G(x)^T H G(x) b dx $$
where
$$ b \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times 1} $$
$$ H \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m} $$
$$ G = (xI - H)^{-1} $$

Comment: Did you try to solve in depth the case $n=1$? The result is already enlightening for the general case...

Comment: Yes I did. I made an edit to remove the unnecessary terms.

Comment: True, $a^\top a$ was unnecessary, but my point was that you should **show** your computations in the $n=1$ case, and the result you arrived at in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You may decompose the non-Hermitian operator $H$:

$$ H = \sum_m h_m \vert m \rangle \langle \tilde{m} \vert $$

and express the result in terms of the pseudoeigenvalues.